# Content div overlays full width image instead of being pushed down

Tags: jquery, html, css, fullscreen

I have a full width image:

```
.image {
    background-image: url(http://cdn1.tnwcdn.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2014/06/wallpaper_51.jpg);
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat:  !important; 
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: #2b6c72;
}
```

Above this I have a hidden menu, that is being triggered by a button (top right corner). When the menu is open, it pushes down the full width image.

Below the full width image I have a green content area. When the hidden menu is open, the content area overlays the full width image instead of being pushed down.

```
#content-wrapper {
    top: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1280px;
    height: 400px;
    background: #3C9;
    margin: 0px auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;   
}
```

**QUESTION** - How can I get the content area pushed down instead of overlaying the image, when my menu is open?

You can see it in action in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5bfvq5Lp/1/)

Comment: the green area is getting pushed down with the image in your fiddle. at least it is in mozilla.

Comment: I am using Firefox, and it is not being pushed down in my browser. It is overlaying the full width image

Comment: I had to make with window wider. I  see it now.

Comment: okay. Have you by any chance had similar problem?

Comment: I can see your issue. I would solve it by making all the elements standard `block` elements with `position:static`. Give the empty `.image div` a suitable height, e.g. `600px`; Then use jquery `slideToggle()` on your `nav`. You may need something to dynamically resolve the `div` height if a fixed height isn't good enough.

Comment: if I give the `.image`-class 600px, then it the image wouldn't fill the entire browser window. I think it can be done with CSS, see this example: http://www.voetsdesign.com/

Comment: I can't get it to happen in Chrome or Firefox. How wide does the screen need to be?

Comment: What can't you make happen?

Comment: I can't get the problem to happen. I don't see the content area overlaying the image. The image always gets pushed down... All I see is an image, then when I click the button a pink (not green) menu pushes the image down, both in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Oh, nevermind. I had to scroll down a bit...my screen isn't tall enough I guess. Now I see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution my self, I think.

I wrapped the `.image` and `#content-wrapper` in a new div the is absolute positioned and set this to 100% in width and height.

```
#wrapper {
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Now it seems like it is acting as intended - when menu is open it pushes all content below, downwards.

See the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5bfvq5Lp/2/

Please let me know if you experience other things.

Comment: enjoy the benefit of "an answer your own question" by ticking it for a few points... points make prizes.